# Uncaught TypeError: element.removeClass is not a function In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, removeclass

I Using This [Sample](http://nimblegecko.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-3-validation-states-with-asp-net-mvc-forms/) For Validate My form, But Got this Error:

**Uncaught TypeError: element.removeClass is not a function** 
says removeClass() Is Not Function !! 
I'm confused

My **Js** Code :

```
$(function () {
            var form = $('#CompanyStep')
              , formData = $.data(form[0])
              , settings = formData.validator.settings
              , oldErrorPlacement = settings.errorPlacement
              , oldSuccess = settings.success;

            settings.errorPlacement = function (label, element) {

                debugger;
                oldErrorPlacement(label, element);

                label.parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
                label.addClass('text-danger');
                element.addClass('form-control-danger');
            };

            settings.success = function (label, element) {

                debugger;

                label.parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
                label.parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
                element.removeClass('form-control-danger');
                element.addClass('form-control-success');


                oldSuccess(label, element);
            };
        });
```

Comment: is label.parents('.form-group') a jquery object?

Comment: What is element? How is the method called? My guess is, it is not a jQuery object.

Comment: @Loaf And how do yu get that when the code above does not show the method being called.... element is an argument and we do not see how it is set

Comment: lable Object no problem, Just removeClass() and addClass()

Comment: why says addClass or removeClass is not function()

Comment: Maybe try `$(element).removeClass('form-control-danger')` instead.

Comment: @loaf Thanks So Much My Friend Fixed :)

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh You're welcome :)

Comment: use .removeClass, not .RemoveClass

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer

Instead try:

```
$(element).removeClass('form-control-danger');
```

Comment: Ok, why does this work though?

Comment: @Telarian this is because what they were passing into `setting.success` for `element` was not a jquery object, so wrapping it around `$()` allows you to use `removeClass()` which is a jQuery function. I cannot tell 100% but it was probably just a DOM object.

jQuery will take any DOM object to the main `$()` function, allowing you to use jQuery functions/etc on it.